# How to toggle a word selection view (change height) in iOS custom keyboard?

Tags: ios, ios8, ios-app-extension

[image]

I'd to like to add a word selection view similar to the above in an iOS 8 custom keyboard.

1. How can I change the keyboard view rectangle size dynamically? and
2. notify the active app (such as the built-in Messages app) to reposition the input bar correspondingly?

UPDATE: based on [this](http://9to5mac.com/2014/08/28/android-keyboard-maker-minuum-previews-variable-height-keyboard-for-ios-8/), the height of keyboard is customisable. How can that be possible?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**It IS possible to change the size of the keyboard in the current iOS 8**

Taken verbatim from the documentation: "**In iOS 8.0, you can adjust a custom keyboard’s height any time after its primary view initially draws on screen.**"

To resize your custom keyboard, add a simple layout constraint.

```
CGFloat _expandedHeight = 500;
NSLayoutConstraint *_heightConstraint = 
    [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem: self.view 
                                 attribute: NSLayoutAttributeHeight 
                                 relatedBy: NSLayoutRelationEqual 
                                    toItem: nil 
                                 attribute: NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute 
                                multiplier: 0.0 
                                  constant: _expandedHeight];
[self.view addConstraint: _heightConstraint];
```

For more information look at Apple's prerelease documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/Keyboard.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH16-SW11)!

Answer (score 2):

You want to change the size and contents of **input accessory view** based on input. Not the frame of the keyboard (input view). The areas you marked with red rectangles are input accessory views in two different states.

[image]

`UIKit` posts keyboard related notifications.

- `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification`,
- `UIKeyboardDidShowNotification`,
- `UIKeyboardWillHideNotification`
- `UIKeyboardDidHideNotification`

The object listening for these notifications can get geometry information related to the input view - like height of the keyboard - to adjust the edited views.

#### Getting notified about the text change.

To change the input accessory view based on input you have to first observe changes in its contents. You can do it either by implementing the `UITextFieldDelegate`'s `textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:`
 method or listening for `UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification`.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self    
                                         selector:@selector(handleTextFieldDidChangeNotification:) 
                                             name:UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification       
                                           object:_textFieldInInputAccessoryView];
```

#### Handling the text change.

The key is to change the input accessory view contents and size when the change in the text field occurs. UIKit attaches the input accessory view to the top of the input view (keyboard). What you have to do is to update the frame of the input accessory view if you want to add an extra line with controls below the text field.

```
- (void)handleTextFieldDidChangeNotification:(NSNotification *)notification
{
     // Update the contents/frame of the input accessory view.

     // Reload the input views.
     [_yourTextField reloadInputViews];
}
```

Based on Text [Programming Guide for iOS - Custom Views for Data Input](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/InputViews/InputViews.html)

Comment: My question is about extending the view dimension _inside a custom keyboard_. It is not about how to use the accessory view _from_ an app. Custom keyboard is new feature of iOS 8.

Comment: Just a small correction to this answer: the area highlighted for the input accessory view is too big - it should be just the single line of suggested words. The controls above that belong to the original text field.

Answer (score 0):

You can not use the custom keyboard APIs in iOS 8 to extend the keyboard past its default frame. I know this from asking an Apple engineer this question at WWDC this year.

Comment: Sad to know. Thanks for the info!

Comment: This information is outdated as of the latest betas. Keyboards can be resized. Refer this section: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/Keyboard.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH16-SW11 and search for "height" on this page (in your browser). Quote from the documentation - "In iOS 8.0, you can adjust a custom keyboard’s height any time after its primary view initially draws on screen."

Comment: However, you still CANNOT draw outside whatever frame you've requested. Consider the screenshot - http://i.imgur.com/aDSyGvl.png. I've resized the keyboard (just a black view for now) to 320 points vertically (larger than usual), and added a yellow subview on top, which is of height 40 points. But only 20 points are shown, since the keyboard is unable to draw outside its bounds. Crude example, but it works.

Comment: hello i am using xocde beta 5 and beta 6 and want to increase the height of keyboard but still it cant work. i use same cord as provide in apple doc. whats the problem is? help me